# Reading password secured urls - Node JS - mysql - javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a list of image urls in a mysql database. When the client sends some GET request to the server, the server responds with a JSON file that will enable the client to build a template and fill  tags, so, nothing complicated.

Recently, the images have been secured by password, so, for example, i can't access them anymore with :

> http://www.url.com/image

but I have to use :

> http://user:password@www.url.com/image

I can't change that since I am not the admin for this images location.

For now, I am doing some dirty substring operations, server side, just after my SELECT request, to add the "user:password@" information to the url string, before sending it to the client.

It works but I think it is dirty and not very secured. What can I do to make it clean ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Your image service has decided to adopt *basic authentication* over http. That means they have decided to adopt a protocol that's grossly insecure. This basic authentication needs https to avoid leaking usernames and passwords to the internet.

That's their problem. But if those usernames and passwords are valuable, it is a serious problem.

Your technique of embedding a username and password in the URL is correct. But it is presently deprecated by some browsers; you should avoid relying on it.